# Google не одобряет загрузку расширения в Google Store

Tags: chrome-extension

Google отклоняет загрузку расширения в магазин, написав следующее:

> Where possible, make as much of your code visible in the package as you can. If some of your app's logic is hidden and it appears to be suspicious, we may remove it.

Судя по ответу, мне стало ясно, что он не пропускает кое-какой файл `.js`, который загружается не из самого расширения, а с сервера. Как можно обойти это ограничение? Загружать код файла в само расширение не выход, нужно, чтобы оно загружалось с сервера.

Может быть, нужно что-то в манифесте прописать?

Comment: От того, что вы что-то пропишете в манифесте, расширение не перестанет загружать файл с сервера. Практически наверняка это не нравится гуглу и их можно понять.

Comment: Ну может быть прописав специальный код в манифесте гугл будет предупреждать пользователя перед установкой, что расширения может быть опасным ну или что-то в этом роде.

Comment: Вы предлагаете гуглу перенести принятие решения на ничего не понимающих пользователей?

Comment: вынесите ваш вредоносный код в какой-нибудь скриптовый язык (типа Lua), встройте в ваше приложение JS-интерпретатор этого языка, грузите невинный текстовый или XML файл (гугл не будет против?) и выполняйте скрипт из него.